# Collapsible not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button containing a div with contents. When clicking the div, I want the collapsed content to expand. Upon hovering above the div, it changes color and the pointer changes, just as I like. However, upon clicking nothing happens: the collapsed content does not expand. What is wrong with my code?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("contents");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var collapse = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (collapse.style.display === "block") {
      collapse.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      collapse.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="results">

  <button type="button" class="contents">
          <div class="info">
            ...
          </div>
          </button>
  <div class="collapse">
    <p>Text only shown when expanding</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the first time your script is fired, there is no var set to check if display is set on block or none., you can sort your script the other way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...It worked when I put the script tag at the end instead of in the head section!

Comment: Moving the script tag to body instead of head resolved it for me as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) as a client-side framework for better performance, cross-browser and fewer lines of code.

You can use `$('.collapse').slideToggle()` function for your project. [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)